# Golang bson.E not declared by package bson

Tags: database, mongodb, go, bson

Currently working on a Golang project but in some controllers i get

```
package controller
import (    
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

var updatedObj primitive.D
updatedObj = append(updatedObj, bson.E{"table", order.Table_id})
```

I always get (bson.E) E is not declared by package bson

Comment: Could you please share the library you are using for BSON? It should be in the imports at the top of any of the source files you are mentioning. Without knowing which library you are using we can't help you.

Comment: Okay i have set it

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are importing the wrong `bson` package.

As you can see [here](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson), `gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson` does not include the "E" type.

Based on the other packages you are using, I think perhaps you want [this one](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson):  `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson`? The `primitive` package you are using is a subpackage of this package so I think the two should work together correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because bson doesn't have any `E` included in their package (because it is reading the other package: `gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson`).

You can try something like this:

```golang
package controller
import (    
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

var updatedObj primitive.D
updatedObj = append(updatedObj, primitive.E{"table", order.Table_id})
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/users/13415116/phonaputer

I actually  imported the wrong package for bson

```
  import (
        "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    )
```

This solved the error and it became correct

```
import (
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    )
    var updatedObj primitive.D
    updatedObj = append(updatedObj, bs.E{"table", order.Table_id})
```